# How does one access the default music folder in Ipad?

Tags: xamarin.ios

My app presently access the default pictures folder of the Ipad with this: 
    **string imagePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures);**.

I am trying to do the same thing with the music folder with this: 
    **string audioPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyMusic);**

It does not work.., what am I doing wrong? It comes across like there are no files in the music folder and they were synch using itunes.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 4 there is an [iPod library](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/iPodLibraryAccess_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) that allows you to do this.  Not sure exactly how this is exposed in MonoTouch, but you should be able to do it.

Comment: Jason, I am new to the IOS world coming from Bill Gates world. My app requires that the user select a music file from the default music folder, how do I get to it? This is very frustrating....

Comment: Corrected my answer - there is actually a library to do this in iOS 4